# How to add filtered row From Table inside Dataset that already get 3 other Tables?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I've problem in adding another Table and this is my Code

```
rptSalarList3_En SalaryListReport3 = new rptSalarList3_En();
                    ds = clsReports.ViewSalaryPaySlipListReport(parameters[0], PaySlip3.dtmFromDate, PaySlip3.dtmToDate);
                    dsReports.Tables.Clear();
                    dsReports.Tables.Add(ds.Tables[0].Copy());
                    dsReports.Tables.Add(ds.Tables[1].Copy());
                    dsReports.Tables.Add(ds.Tables[2].Copy());
                    DataTable dt1 = dsReports.Tables[0].Copy();
                    DataRow Dr = dt1.Rows[0];
                    DataRow[] result = dsReports.Tables[0].Select("SalaryItemName = 'Variable'");
                    dt1.Rows.Clear();
                    dt1.Rows.Add(result[0].ItemArray);
                    DataSet DsTaxable = new DataSet();
                    DsTaxable.Tables.Add(dt1);
                    dsReports.Tables.Add(DsTaxable.Tables[0]);                        
                    dsReports.Tables.Add(dsLogo.Tables[0].Copy());
                    dsReports.Tables[0].TableName = "SalaryListItems";
                    dsReports.Tables[1].TableName = "Preferences";
                    dsReports.Tables[2].TableName = "SalaryItemDetails";
                    dsReports.Tables[3].TableName = "SalaryItemTaxable";
```

The Problem is when having filter from first table it raise error message that said 
(ex.Message = "DataTable already belongs to another DataSet.")

and I want to take the Filtered value from First Table and make it Table so I can add it To dsReports to Show in Crystal Report

Comment: Man you use `.Copy()` everywhere but not here `dsReports.Tables.Add(DsTaxable.Tables[0]);` why you do that? :)

Comment: yes this is where I tried to pass the dataset and it refuse here with this message
ex.Message = "DataTable already belongs to another DataSet."

Comment: What i'm trying to say is, use `.Copy()` there too. Because as it is, it's trying to move the table from one dataset to another. You can't do that, right?

Comment: yes that's Right i tried it and it is workin thanks man

Answer (score 0):

Using  **.Copy()** like other Tables helped me to get same data from first table which need to be filtered
and can added to current DataSet